# How to show images while call a soap web service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, web-services, soap

im building an app which consumes data from a Soap Web Service, i just want to show a couples images in the screen to let the user know that the data is being downloaded from the web, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to try [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). Tt displays a translucent HUD with an indicator and/or labels while work is being done in a background thread. It works great. Please explore it!

**Alternatively**, you can try this custom loading overlay. I have been using this for one of my project and it works great. Here, in the image view I am animating 10 different images so as to look nice on screen. You can remove the animation based on your needs and pass your own images.

```
#import "MyLoadingOverlay.h"

@implementation MyLoadingOverlay

+ (id)loadingOverlayInView:(UIView *)iSuperview {
    return [MyLoadingOverlay loadingOverlayInView:iSuperview title:nil fullScreen:NO spinner:YES showCustomImages:NO];
}


+ (id)loadingOverlayInView:(UIView *)iSuperview title:(NSString *)iTitle fullScreen:(BOOL)iFullscreen spinner:(BOOL)iShowSpinner {
    return [MyLoadingOverlay loadingOverlayInView:iSuperview title:iTitle fullScreen:iFullscreen spinner:iShowSpinner showCustomImages:NO];
}


+ (id)loadingOverlayInView:(UIView *)iSuperview title:(NSString *)iTitle fullScreen:(BOOL)iFullscreen spinner:(BOOL)iShowSpinner showCustomImages:(BOOL)iShowCustomImages {
    MyLoadingOverlay *anOverlay = [[MyLoadingOverlay alloc] initWithFrame:[iSuperview bounds]];

    if (!anOverlay) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Set our full screen attribute
    anOverlay.fullScreen = iFullscreen;
    anOverlay.showSpinner = iShowSpinner;

    anOverlay.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    anOverlay.opaque = NO;
    anOverlay.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [iSuperview addSubview:anOverlay];

    CGFloat theLabelWidth = anOverlay.frame.size.width;
    const CGFloat DEFAULT_LABEL_HEIGHT = 50.0;
    CGRect aFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theLabelWidth, DEFAULT_LABEL_HEIGHT);

    UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];

    if (iTitle) {
        aLabel.text = iTitle;
        aLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        aLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        aLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        aLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]];
        aLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        aLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
        aLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

        [anOverlay addSubview:aLabel];
    }

    CGFloat aLabelYOffset = 0;

    if (anOverlay.showSpinner && !iShowCustomImages) {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *aSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        [anOverlay addSubview:aSpinner];
        aSpinner.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        [aSpinner startAnimating];

        CGRect aSpinnerRect = aSpinner.frame;
        aSpinnerRect.origin.x = floorf(0.5 * (anOverlay.frame.size.width - aSpinnerRect.size.width));
        aSpinnerRect.origin.y = floorf(0.5 * (anOverlay.frame.size.height - aSpinnerRect.size.height));
        aSpinner.frame = aSpinnerRect;

        aLabelYOffset = aSpinnerRect.origin.y + 32.0;
    } else {
        UIImage *aMyImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"My_Loading_" duration:1.0];
        aLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:185.0/255.0 green:185.0/255.0 blue:185.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:aMyImage];
        anImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        [anOverlay addSubview:anImageView];

        CGRect anImageRect = anImageView.frame;
        anImageRect.origin.x = floorf(0.5 * (anOverlay.frame.size.width - anImageRect.size.width));
        anImageRect.origin.y = floorf(0.5 * (anOverlay.frame.size.height - anImageRect.size.height));
        anImageView.frame = anImageRect;

        aLabelYOffset = anImageRect.origin.y + 32.0;    
    }

    aFrame.origin.x = floorf(0.5 * (anOverlay.frame.size.width - theLabelWidth));
    aFrame.origin.y = aLabelYOffset;    
    aLabel.frame = aFrame;

    // Set up the fade-in animation
    CATransition *aTransition = [CATransition animation];
    [aTransition setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [[iSuperview layer] addAnimation:aTransition forKey:@"layerAnimation"];

    return anOverlay;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma instance methods

- (void)addToView:(UIView *)iSuperview {
    [iSuperview addSubview:self];
    // Set up the fade-in animation
    CATransition *aTransition = [CATransition animation];
    [aTransition setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [[iSuperview layer] addAnimation:aTransition forKey:@"layerAnimation"];
}


- (void)removeView {
    if (self.fullScreen) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    } else {
        UIView *aSuperview = [self superview];
        [super removeFromSuperview];
        // Set up the animation for image loading overlay
        CATransition *aTransition = [CATransition animation];
        [aTransition setType:kCATransitionFade];

        [[aSuperview layer] addAnimation:aTransition forKey:@"layerAnimation"];
    }
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)iRect {
    if (!self.fullScreen) {
        iRect.size.height -= 1;
        iRect.size.width -= 1;

        const CGFloat RECT_PADDING = 4.0;
        iRect = CGRectInset(iRect, RECT_PADDING, RECT_PADDING);

        const CGFloat ROUND_RECT_CORNER_RADIUS = 5.0;
        CGPathRef aPath = copyPathWithRoundRect(iRect, ROUND_RECT_CORNER_RADIUS);

        CGContextRef aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        const CGFloat BACKGROUND_OPACITY = 0.0;
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(aContext, 0, 0, 0, BACKGROUND_OPACITY);
        CGContextAddPath(aContext, aPath);
        CGContextFillPath(aContext);

        const CGFloat STROKE_OPACITY = 0.25;
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(aContext, 1, 1, 1, STROKE_OPACITY);
        CGContextAddPath(aContext, aPath);
        CGContextStrokePath(aContext);
        CGPathRelease(aPath);
    } else {
        CGContextRef aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        const CGFloat BACKGROUND_OPACITY = 0.75;
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(aContext, 0, 0, 0, BACKGROUND_OPACITY);
        CGContextFillRect(aContext, iRect);
    }
}


@end
```